# Run OR statement in SQLiteOpenHelper for the same column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a function in my `DatabaseHelper` class (extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`) that returns row based on a certain column's value. Code snippet as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOCATIONS, new String[]{}, COLUMN_PROD_ID+"=?", productId, null, null, null);
```

Where productId is a `String[]` that contains only 1 value.

Now I want to reuse the same function for matching 2 values for the same column. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = VALUE1 OR COLUMN1 = VALUE2;
```

How can I achieve this in `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Kindly bear with me if this is a stupid question. Thanks.

Comment: By using `rawQuery()`, it would be so much easier!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein even with `rawQuery()` because the query string needs to be different for different number of parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

The WHERE clause is the `selection` parameter; just change it approrpiately:

```java
String selection;
switch (productIdsArray.length) {
case 1: selection = COLUMN_PROD_ID + " = ?";
        break;
case 2: selection = COLUMN_PROD_ID + " = ? OR " + COLUMN_PROD_ID + " = ?";
        break;
default: // blow up
}
db.query(TABLE_LOCATIONS, new String[]{},
         selection, productIdsArray,
         null, null, null);
```

Comment: But then I won't be able to reuse the same function if I pass `productId` array with only 1 value.

Comment: Just saw the edit, that's what I did eventually. Accepting!